Problem with circular Relashionship in async SQLAlchemy
I have the following sqlalchemy structure for some objects:
from typing import Optional

from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase, mapped_column, relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm.base import Mapped


class Test(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "test"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    value: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    attributes: Mapped[list["TestAttribute"]] = relationship(
        "TestAttribute", back_populates="test", primaryjoin="Test.id == TestAttribute.test_id", lazy="selectin"
    )
    test_attributes: Mapped[list["TestAttribute"]] = relationship(
        "TestAttribute",
        back_populates="test_attribute",
        primaryjoin="Test.id == TestAttribute.test_attribute_id",
    )


class TestAttribute(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = "test_attribute"
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    test_value: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
    test_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("test.id"), nullable=False)
    test_attribute_id: Mapped[Optional[int]] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("test.id"), nullable=True)
    test: Mapped["Test"] = relationship(back_populates="attributes", foreign_keys=[test_id])
    test_attribute: Mapped[Optional["Test"]] = relationship(
        back_populates="test_attributes", foreign_keys=[test_attribute_id], lazy="joined"
    )



There is a Test object that has TestAttribute attributes. They are connected one to many. Also, TestAttribute is associated with another Test object (which may also have its own attributes). I also have the following pydantic schemes for working with these models:
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict
from typing import Optional


class TestAttributeSchema(BaseModel):
    test_attribute_id: Optional[int]
    test_value: int
    test_attribute: Optional["TestSchema"]
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)


class TestSchema(BaseModel):
    id: int
    value: int
    attributes: list[TestAttributeSchema]
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)

There is also the following repository class for getting a Test object by id:
class TestRepository:
    
    @staticmethod
    async def get(id: int) -> TestSchema:
        async with async_session_maker() as session:
            result = await session.execute(
                select(Test).where(Test.id == id)
            )
            data = result.scalars().one_or_none()
            if data:
                return TestSchema.model_validate(data)
            return None

    @staticmethod
    async def list() -> list[TestSchema]:
        async with async_session_maker() as session:
            result = await session.execute(select(Test))
            return [TestSchema.model_validate(i) for i in result.scalars().all()]

Problem: if the test object has attributes that also refer to test objects with attributes that also have links to test objects, etc. (at the data level, it is guaranteed that this sequence converges!), then I get the following error when validating with pydantic when calling the TestRepository.get method:
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 1 validation error for TestSchema
attributes.0.test_attribute.attributes
  Error extracting attribute: MissingGreenlet: greenlet_spawn has not been called; can't call await_only() here. Was IO attempted in an unexpected place? (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/xd2s) [type=get_attribute_error, input_value=<src.db.test.Test object at 0x7fadc2b01b90>, input_type=Test]

The funny thing is that there is no such problem when calling the TestRepository.list method! Everything works out as intended.
An example of a correctly executed program in the case of list:
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 1,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "test_attribute_id": 2,
        "test_value": 1,
        "test_attribute": {
          "id": 2,
          "value": 2,
          "attributes": [
            {
              "test_attribute_id": 3,
              "test_value": 1,
              "test_attribute": {
                "id": 3,
                "value": 3,
                "attributes": [
                  {
                    "test_attribute_id": 4,
                    "test_value": 1,
                    "test_attribute": {
                      "id": 4,
                      "value": 4,
                      "attributes": []
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "test_attribute_id": 3,
        "test_value": 1,
        "test_attribute": {
          "id": 3,
          "value": 3,
          "attributes": [
            {
              "test_attribute_id": 4,
              "test_value": 1,
              "test_attribute": {
                "id": 4,
                "value": 4,
                "attributes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 2,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "test_attribute_id": 3,
        "test_value": 1,
        "test_attribute": {
          "id": 3,
          "value": 3,
          "attributes": [
            {
              "test_attribute_id": 4,
              "test_value": 1,
              "test_attribute": {
                "id": 4,
                "value": 4,
                "attributes": []
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "value": 3,
    "attributes": [
      {
        "test_attribute_id": 4,
        "test_value": 1,
        "test_attribute": {
          "id": 4,
          "value": 4,
          "attributes": []
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "value": 4,
    "attributes": []
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "value": 5,
    "attributes": []
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "value": 6,
    "attributes": []
  }
]


It looks like "where" is somehow interfering. I tried to do a select of all with where and it doesn't work either.

I don't know if this applies to your problem but I encountered this error using the async library of SQLAlchemy when accessing fields of a model which would under the hood send a query to the database. This was because I didn't specify a loading strategy an the default was "lazy loading". Changing it to "joined loading" resolved the issue for me, but this isn't senseful for each use case as it would create possibly giant queries if you configure each relationship like this.

Calling the list method doesn't throw this error because it is async. So, the query can be awaited without a problem by SQLAlchemy. But when accessing the attribute SQLAlchemy tries to add the query task to an event loop I believe? However, it doesn't work, if the data weren't loaded on beforehand I think.

One further comment: This "Greenlet" error originates from SQLAchemy, not pydantic. It just happens to occure while you're validating a pydantic object. And as far as I know it means something like "Couldn't await query blabla".
